# $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n <\infty$ implies $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n a_n^2 <\infty$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $a_n>0$ for all $n$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n <\infty$. Is it true that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n a_n^2 <\infty$? I can prove that if $a_n$ is a decreasing sequence, then this is true. But I don't know in general case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.  Try  $a_{2^k} = 1/k^2$, $a_n = 1/n^2$ if $n$ is not a power of $2$.
Then $2^k a_{2^k}^2 = 2^k/k^4 \to \infty$, so $\sum_n n a_n^2 = \infty$.

Comment: Clever example, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I missed the hypothesis that $a_n>0$. It's certainly false without this, but as Robert Israel showed, it's false with it as well.

This is false in general. Note that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ converges, but $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\left(\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\right)^2 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}
$$
diverges.

Comment: Note the assumption $a_n > 0$.

Comment: @John Here is a positive series

Comment: Whoops....... :D

Comment: Don't just say whoops, either delete your answer or fix it.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I inserted a disclaimer.